# Selenium grid 4: how to display the docker ui?

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-grid

I’m training at selenium and docker right now. For this I created a project by following this tutorial that explains how to set up a selenium grid with docker compose.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjQ5zZM7fpI

I also went to the docker-selenium repository and used the following yml file:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3.yml

The grid is correctly configured when I navigate to:
http://localhost:4444/ui/index.html#/
The 3 nodes appear in the hub. However I do not know how to get the ui of docker which is shown in the tutorial where we see the images of the containers.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

I’m a little ashamed to ask this question but I looked for a moment and I discovered docker since this morning...
How do I get this interface ?

My configuration:

-Linux Ubuntu 20.04

-Google and chrome 95

-the last version selenium server : 4.1.1

-a docker account

Thanks

Comment: That is called Docker Desktop, which is not available on Linux (yet)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer